# Prove that this function is a contraction

Tags: calculus, functions, contraction-operator

Let $f \in C^2([a,b])$ be a function with the following properties:

(i) $f(a)f(b) <0 $

(ii) $f'(x) \neq 0$  $\forall x$

(iii) $\frac{|f(a)|} {|f'(a)|} <(b-a)$ and $\frac{|f(b)|} {|f'(b)|} <(b-a)$

(iv) $ f''(x) \leq 0$ $\forall x$

Then $h(x) := x-\frac{f(x)} {f'(x)} $ is a contraction.

What I did is:

Suppose wlog $f(a)<0<f(b)$ and so $f'(x)>0$. We have
$|h'(x)| \leq... \leq L<1$
I don't know how to do the middle part, maybe we have $\frac{|f(x)|} {|f'(x)|} <(b-a)$ $\forall x$? (not sure)

Curiosity: thie statement will prove a theorem of converge for the Newton method

Comment: We can prove that $\frac{|f(x)|}{|f'(x)|} < b-a$ for all $x$. Indeed, $f$ is increasing since $f' >0$  while $f'$ is decreasing by assumption, so that $\frac{f}{f'}$ is increasing. Since the inequality is satisfied at both endpoints, it must be true for all $x \in [a,b]$.